# Exclude Property in Search Results Web Part using custom Search Criteria

Tags: search, search-results

Is it possible to exclude a property from what is returned in the Search Results Web Part?  For example, I have a property named 'TestProperty'.  I need it indexed because I use it in my Search Criteria for other logic, but I dont want Search to include it in what user is searching for (i.e. I dont want the value of searchboxquery to look in 'TestProperty').

I tried this:  -TestProperty:{searchboxquery}

The problem with this is if what user is searching for is in 'TestProperty' it eliminates those records from what Search returns.  If what the user is searching is in another property I want Search to return those records.

So if user searches for 'dodge' and that value is in 'TestProperty' and 'MakeProperty'. I would want search to return it because it is in 'MakeProperty;.  If 'dodge' was only in 'TestProperty' I wouldnt want Search to return that record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the setting on the managed property. Uncheck "Retrievable" and it won't return in the query. If you don't want it influencing the query uncheck "Searchable".